# How can I create a large number of users to bootstrap DHIS 2?

Tags: dhis2

I need to create and on-board a large number of user accounts in DHIS 2. It seems cumbersome to enter them one by one, and importing the users has the problem that I cannot securely distribute passwords. What would be a good approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the user invitation feature, which will send an invitation to create an account to people over email. This will allow people to enter their personal information and password in a secure form, hence avoiding default passwords or passwords being sent over insecure channels like email.

To use user invitations, make sure that the system has a properly configured SMTP email server under apps > settings > email. To send an invitation, go to apps > users > add new. Under action select "Email invitation to create account", then enter an email address, user roles and optionally a username. If you specify a username it will be enforced, if not it will be up to the user to specify it.